# Checking format of timestamp with time zone variable in oracle plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, timestamp-with-timezone

I need to create a oracle plsql script which have input param v_date as **Timestamp with time zone** type.
Also I need to verify whether the format of the v_date is as per mentioned format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM' or not .
How should I achieve this?

I was thinking of achieveing this by changing input param v_date as **String**  and then convert this string into **Timestamp with time zone** and if any error occured while converting then conclude that the format is wrong. But it seems **TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ** functions doesn't throw error when the date string is in different format w.r.t the specified format instead it converts it.

For e.g.

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('15-APR-15',
   'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM') FROM DUAL;
```

Actual result : `14-APR-15 11.50.00.000000000 PM AMERICA/CHICAGO`

Expected result : `Some error as format is not as per  'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM'`

In short I want to know how to verify the format of **Timestamp with time zone** type.

Comment: There is  a typo in the query , correct query :                                                              SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('15-APR-15 ', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM') FROM DUAL;

Comment: How will you be converting the value to a string in order to pass it in? Where is the value coming from, and why do you think you can't just leave the parameter as Timestamp with time zone?

Comment: My actual story says, accept input param v_date in the format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" and then verify that the value passed in for v_date is in given "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" format.                                          Till now whatever R&D I did on this, it seems  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" is not valid timestamp format in oracle.                     So now I am trying to implement the story with v_Date as string in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM' and then use TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ() to verify the format of the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the "fx" modifier to the format, which says to Oracle "expect this exact format":

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('15-APR-15 ', 'fxYYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM') FROM DUAL;

SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('15-APR-15 ', 'fxYYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM') FROM DUAL
                       *
Error at line 1
ORA-01862: the numeric value does not match the length of the format item
```